# Find duplicates in Select statement after an if check

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, group-by

I am working on a project that keeps a track of repaired cell phones.

In the select statement, I would like to find the duplicate IMEI numbers and check if the AddedDate between the duplicates is less than 30 days. Another words, the select should list all the phones even including the duplicated IMEI numbers if the AddedDate is more than 30 days.

I hope I described it clear enough. Thank you.

Additional notes:

I have tried it by including groupBy under a sub-select which did find the duplicates, but I wasn't able to implement an if condition. Instead, I was going to place all duplicates into a dynamic table and then use a select statement against this table. Before doing so, I thought of posting my question here.

For example DB_Phones has the following rows

ID - AddedDate - IMEI

1 - 01.10.2012 - 123456789012345

2 - 15.10.2012 - 987654321012345

3 - 20.10.2012 - 123456789012345

Based on the table above, I would like to list only the second row (ID# 2) because the last duplicate (ID# 3) wasn't added 30 days after the row with the ID# 1. If rows were as below:

ID - AddedDate - IMEI

1 - 01.10.2012 - 123456789012345

2 - 15.10.2012 - 987654321012345

3 - 20.10.2012 - 123456789012345

4 - 21.11.2012 - 123456789012345

Then the second and fourth row should be returned. I need to return just one of the duplicates (last one) if the 30 day condition is met.

I hope it make more sense now. Thanks again.

Comment: The answer to this will depend greatly on your schema. Are repairs in a different table than IMEI numbers? what are the field names?

Comment: post your schema and data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and come back here with the URL pointing there.  it is hard to get an idea what you need by your description

Comment: Do you need to return both duplicates or just one of them and which one.

Comment: I have added additional notes to my question above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A guess at what you're after:

```
SELECT
  r.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Repairs r2 WHERE r.IMEI = r2.IMEI
  AND r.ID != r2.ID) as NumberOfAllDuplicates,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Repairs r2 WHERE r.IMEI = r2.IMEI
  AND ABS(DATEDIFF(day, r.AddedDate, r2.AddedDate)) < 30
  AND r.ID != r2.ID) as NumberOfNearDuplicates
FROM
  Repairs r
```

This depends on having an ID field, and everything existing in one table. With the correlated sub queries, it may not be very fast on long data.